# Errors on Add-Migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, identity

A few weeks ago I enabled migration on my project and added a column 'ClientID' to the AspNetUsers table.

Now I'm trying to add another column: "Name".

I ran this command in the Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Add-Migration "Name"
```

And I got the following error:

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following
>   explicit migrations are pending: [20161081751088_InitialCreate,
>   20161091825212_ClientID]. Apply the pending explicit migrations
>   before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

I ran an update command:

```
PM> Update-Database
```

But:

> There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.

I researched online and found this solution:

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialMigrations -IgnoreChanges
```

But then I got the first error again:

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following
>   explicit migrations are pending: [20161081751088_InitialCreate,
>   20161091825212_ClientID]. Apply the pending explicit migrations
>   before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you've already update the DB, try using `Update-Database -TargetMigration [PreviousMigrationName]` to rollback with previous migration version, then delete it. Other way to consider with is excluding/deleting both `[20161081751088_InitialCreate]` & `[20161091825212_ClientID]` in `Migrations` folder from your EF project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove the Migrations folder in your project
2. Delete the `_MigrationHistory` table from your database.
3. Run the `Enable-Migrations` command from your Package Manager Console.
4. Run the `Add-Migration Init` command to create a migration.
5. Remove all of the code lines in `Up()` function for the initial migration. (To create an empty migration and solve the errors that you are facing.)
6. Run the `Update-Database` command to apply your empty migration.
7. Make changes to your code first model for preparing to adding your real migration.
8. Run the `Add-Migration InitNew` command to create a new migration.
9. Run the `Update-Database` command to apply the changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't get the point of #8, could you clarify?

Comment: You're welcome. I mean, create a new migration for your code first model at that step. _InitNew_ is just it's name. You can change it like _Add-Migration MyMigration_ etc.

Comment: Possibly a bit drastic in other similar situations

Answer (score -2):

Firstly try these please :

- 1- clean the project up-root solution
- 2- close the visual studio
- 3- reopen vs and open the solution
- 4- build it.
- 5- totally remove the migrations folder under the entities folder
- 6- remove the table
  _projectnameMigrations from the DB
- 7- open the PMC in Vs
- 8- Enable-Migrations
- 9- Add-Migrations mig_Myinit
- 10- (!Important) clear the up method and make it empty
- 11- update-database
- 12- done

Your next migrations...
point is that if you remove a table manually from the database Entity Framework is not able to recognize it and by default it is accessible so when you are using EF you have to do any database-related tasks from the pmc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help