# Add-Migration not working in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I'm tried to Add-Migration in my asp.net core application but migration not working
Please any one give me ans for this what's the issue

[Please check this image i added all information reading issue everything i combined into single screen-shot for more clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP1nH.png)

Answer (score 1):

you need to provide a name for the migration just like this `Add-Migration V1`, after creating the migration you need to run the `Update-Database` to apply the migration. BTW if there is any build error nothing will work. you need to ensure there is not build error.

Comment: I added name Intial but not working showing stack overflow

Comment: I added name Initial but not working 
showing me stack overflow
There is no any build error everything is fine application is running 
In package-console window also showing Build succeeded.

Comment: if you have any existing migration delete them all using `Remove-Migration` if you have multiple migration then you need to run `Remove-Migration` multiple times, then start over again with `Add-Migration`

Comment: There is no any existing migration i deleted all folder with Migration name also deleted table from Database .I don't know whats the problem in this why not working for me doing all these things.

Comment: here is the check list you need to check:
1. you have a correct database connection, 2. You have a entity, 3. go through the migrations steps starting with `Add-Migration`.

Comment: yes i added migration with these list but i'm facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

1) Remove the Migrations folder in your project

2) Delete the _MigrationHistory table from your database.

3) Run the Enable-Migrations command from your Package Manager Console.

4) Run the Add-Migration Init command to create a migration.

5) Remove all of the code lines in Up() function for the initial migration. (To create an empty migration.)

6) Run the Update-Database command to apply your empty migration.

7) Make changes to your code first model for preparing to adding your real migration.

8) Run the Add-Migration InitNew command to create a new migration.

9)Run the Update-Database command to apply the changes.

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44019743/6221069